# Hashing password while registering new user in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem registering new users to my User database. I want to hash the password while submitting the form. I am not exactly sure how to do it and I'm new to this. I need help guys. My code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/users", name="signingUP")
     */
    public function new(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->add('userName', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Username'))
            ->add('fullName', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Fullname'))
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('label' => 'Email'))
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array('label' => 'Password'))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'))
            ->getForm();
        
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user = $form->getData();

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->render('index.html.twig', array('data' => 'Added to database'));
        }

        return $this->render('users/signUp.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

It adds everything else just the way I want it but cant do with the password

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/doctrine/registration_form.html

Comment: It is a bit interesting that the link @yivi provided was for an old non-supported version of Symfony (4.1).  It does indeed show how to correctly hash a password.  But newer versions of the link basically point to an almost empty big picture sort of page which essentially says to figure it out yourself.  The closest actual example in the current docs I could find is in the [fixtures section](https://symfony.com/doc/master/security.html#c-encoding-passwords).  There are of course many almost duplicate Stack Overflow questions which might also be worth searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Simple pass UserPasswordEncoderInterface to your controller and encode the password

```
 public function new(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder){
        //$user = new User(); <- this is not necessary as long as you set data_class in form to your User class.

        $form = $this->createForm(RegisterType::class); // Move your register form to a RegisterType in Form namespace (less mess in your controllers)

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $user = $form->getData();
            $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword);
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->render('index.html.twig', array('data'=>'Added to database'));
        }
        return $this->render('users/signUp.html.twig', array('form'=>$form->createView()));
    }
```

Also make sure you have an encoder specified in security.yml, although it should be set to auto already.

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...

    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: 'auto'
```